# ffmpeg trimming frame freeze issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I used these command to trim the video:

**without re-encode**

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -to 00:06:49 -c copy out1.ts ffmpeg -ss 00:07:13 -i input.mp4 -c copy out2.ts ffmpeg -i 'concat:out1.ts|out2.ts' -c copy output3.mp4`

**with re-encode**

`ffmpeg -i output000.mp4 -to 00:06:47.430 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -avoid_negative_ts 1 out1.mp4 ffmpeg -ss 00:07:13.399 -i output000.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -avoid_negative_ts 1 out2.mp4 ffmpeg -i 'concat:out1.mp4|out2.mp4' -c copy output3.mp4`

---

`ffmpeg -i input.ts -to 00:06:49 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental out1.ts ffmpeg -ss 00:07:13 -i input.ts -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental out2.ts ffmpeg -i "concat:out1.ts|out2.ts" -c:v copy -c:a copy output3.ts`

---

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -to 00:06:49 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -avoid_negative_ts 1 out1.mp4 ffmpeg -ss 00:07:13 -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -avoid_negative_ts 1 out2.mp4 ffmpeg -i 'concat:out1.mp4|out2.mp4' -c copy output3.mp4`

---

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -to 00:06:49 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental out1.mp4 ffmpeg -ss 00:07:13 -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental out2.mp4 ffmpeg -i 'concat:out1.mp4|out2.mp4' -c copy output3.mp4`

---

`ffmpeg -i input.ts -to 00:06:49 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac out1.ts ffmpeg -ss 00:07:13 -i input.ts -c:v libx264 -c:a aac  out2.ts ffmpeg -i "concat:out1.ts|out2.ts" -c:v copy -c:a copy output3.ts`

These command are works, but it causes the video to freeze for about 1 second wherever I trim it. I have attached a video below to provide an example of the freeze frame issue.

**example** : https://jumpshare.com/v/r510dpNflKUFJEFXQXlP

I tried to trim the video, and it was successfully trimmed. However, the issue of frame freezing still exists in the video